# Fatal error in Magento after upgrading extension

Tags: magento, fatal-error

I am hoping someone may be able to assist with this.  I updated an extension in Magento and am now getting the following error and don't know how to fix this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Fatal error: Class Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::insertIgnore, Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::changeTableAutoIncrement) in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3864

If I change "Class Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql" to "abstract Class Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql" i then get....

"Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php on line 165"

Comment: Upgrading extension did you mean to say core magento functionality or custom made extension ?

Comment: If it's custom extension then there should not be any issue with core functionality as long as core functionality would untouched. :)